# Problemas com o font-face

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou finalizado um site usando o Twitter-Bootstrap.

Estou usando o `@font-face` direto no *style.css* e estou puxando a `font-family` também no *style.css*, na `div` *footer* e aplicando diretamente no `<p>`. Porém não estou obtendo resultados...

Alguém pode me dizer o que há de errado?

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Cinzel';
    src: url('cinzel.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

/* Footer */

footer{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#212121;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:40px 0 0 0;
}
footer .p{
    font-family: 'Cinzel';
}
```

Sim, o arquivo *cinzel.ttf* está diretamente na pasta *CSS*, foi uma tentativa de solução em ser o caminho do arquivo, mas não era...

Comment: `@face-font` deveria ser `@font-face`, certo?

Comment: Perdão, foi erro na hora que fui digitar aqui e depois ficou tudo distorcido, não fosse tua análise nem teria visto rsrs, grato!. Mas, lá no css está correto

Comment: Ahh sim. Vou te ajudar formulando uma resposta. Daí ignoro esse "errinho". ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver seu problema de vez, vou te apresentar uma excelente ferramenta!

1) Download da fonte em questão: [Cinzel](https://ff.static.1001fonts.net/c/i/cinzel.regular.ttf);

2) Acessar a ferramenta [WebFont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) no site [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/);

3) Upar a fonte que acabamos de baixar clicando em *Upload*;

4) Marcar a opção "Expert" e definir as seguintes opções:

[image: Print font-squirrel webfont-generator]

5) Clicar em *Download your kit*;

6) Após extrair os arquivos do *ZIP* que baixou, "pegar" tudo que interessa e copiar para o projeto em questão. Normalmente utilizo estes arquivos:

[image: Arquivos mais importantes]

7) No arquivo **stylesheet.css**, alterar a `url` buscando os arquivos da fonte dentro da pasta `fontes/`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cinzelregular';
    src: url('fontes/cinzel.regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontes/cinzel.regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontes/cinzel.regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fontes/cinzel.regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontes/cinzel.regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontes/cinzel.regular-webfont.svg#cinzelregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Lógico que tem que mover as fontes para esta pasta, exceto o *.css*, heim!

8) Agora é só *linkar* o arquivo *stylesheet.css* e usufruir da sua gloriosa fonte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial Font-face por LipESprY</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .cinzel {
                font-family: 'cinzelregular';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Um texto normal</p>
        <p class="cinzel">Um texto com a fonte Cinzel-regular</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**RESULTADO:**

[image: Resultado final - fonte carregada]

Caso queira baixar o projeto pronto, está no meu [GitHub/LipESprY/sopt-problema-font-face](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-problema-font-face)

> Vale a pena lembrar que alguns navegadores não carregam certos tipos de fontes. Os navegadores mais recentes, normalmente, não passam por esse problema. Com tal ferramenta, você soluciona esses problemas de compatibilidade. Por isso foram gerados vários tipos dessa mesma fonte (*.ttf, .eot, .svg, .woff, .woff2*). **Os problemas com fontes, realmente, acabam de vez!**

**@edit:**

> Existem atualmente quatro formatos de contêiner de fontes usados na Web: EOT, TTF, WOFF e WOFF2. Infelizmente, apesar da grande variedade de opções, não há um único formato universal que funcione em todos os navegadores atuais e antigos: O EOT é compatível somente com o IE, o TTF é parcialmente compatível com o IE, o WOFF oferece a compatibilidade mais ampla, mas não está disponível em alguns navegadores antigos e a compatibilidade com o WOFF 2.0 ainda está sendo desenvolvida em muitos navegadores.
>
> Fonte: [Otimização de fontes da web](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization?hl=pt-br) por [Ilya Grigorik](https://developers.google.com/web/resources/contributors/ilyagrigorik?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Como faço para te agradecer?

Comment: Considere agradecido! Tmj

Comment: Grato, meu amigo! Tu também entende Bootstrap? Estou com uma outra duvidazinha que não consigo resolver, já vi mais de 20 tópicos diferentes sobre a dúvida e soluções que funcionaram com outros comigo não funciona

Comment: Costumo fazer na mão, Bro. Mas posta uma nova pergunta q a comunidade vai te ajudar.

Comment: Grato pela atençãozinha! Feliz Nataaaaaaaaaaaaal!