# Como avaliar se o usuário irá ter a fonte utilizada no site?

Tags: html, css, font, webdesign

Quando o usuário não tem a fonte determinada no arquivo css instalada em seu computador, o browser irá utilizar a fonte do estilo padrão, segundo as apostilas que li.

Por exemplo, você cria um layout voltado para o público jovem, mas por ser uma fonte pouco conhecida, o site acabar em Times New Roman para a maioria dos usuários.

- Existe algum site, portal ou biblioteca que é utilizada para se
  precaver desse risco?

Comment: Não é muito minha área, mas no caso você colocaria mais de uma fonte como salvaguarda.

Comment: Vc está usando algum CDN de fonte como o Google Fonte? Ou está usando algum `@font-face` com a fonte customizada? Vc precisa dar mais detalhes, e se possível incluir seu CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via CSS você pode fazer uma lista de fontes a serem consideradas para tal elemento. Caso o navegador não encontre a primeira, ele busca a segunda. Se não encontrar a segunda, ele busca a terceira. E por aí vai...

Exemplo:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Essa nao existe', 'Tahoma', 'Arial', serif, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

No final das contas, o ideal é você disponibilizar as suas fontes no seu site e adicioná-as no seu arquivo `.css`. Para tal, tem uma resposta minha que explica e já resolve os problemas de compatibilidade das fontes em determinados navegadores: [Problemas com o font-face](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/352932/45810). Recomendo veementemente a leitura caso adote esta alternativa.

---

> *A propriedade `font-family` do CSS permite que se faça uma lista de prioridades de familias de fontes e/ou nomes genéricos de famílias a serem especificados para um elemento selecionado. Ao contrário da maioria das demais propriedades CSS, os valores são separados por vírgula para indicar quais são as alternativas. O Browser irá utilizar a primeira fonte da lista que for encontrada no computador, ou poderá fazer o dowload utilizando a informação contida na regra `@font-face`.*
>
> *Programadores WEB devem sempre adicionar pelo menos uma família genérica para a lista de `font-family`, já que não há garantia que aquela fonte específica está instalada no computador, ou possa ser baixada pela regra `@font-face`. A família genérica permite o browser selecionar uma fonte aceita pelo computador, quando necessário.*
>
> *É também conveniente usar de antemão a propriedade `font` para definir a `font-size` e outras propriedades relacionadas a fonte todas de uma só vez.*
>
> Fonte/leitura recomendada: [MDN font-family CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)

---

> "*- Existe algum site, portal ou biblioteca que é utilizada para se precaver desse risco*"

Não exatamente para "precaver desse risco", mas uma excelente **biblioteca de fontes** existe sim: o [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). Hoje conta com 915 fontes e você pode "linkar" direto no seu projeto. Aliás, tem uma pergunta aqui sobre [Como usar as fontes do Google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133483/como-usar-as-fontes-dispon%C3%ADveis-do-google-fonts-no-html). Dê uma olhadinha lá! Já a precaução fica por sua conta, aplicando uma lista de fontes adequada!

Answer (score 0):

> Existe algum site, portal ou biblioteca que é utilizada para se
>   precaver desse risco?

Existe a propriedade `font-family` do `CSS`, você pode listar uma série de fonts para seu documento, elas serão usadas na ordem que você definiu.
Vejamos na prática, imagine que você definiu as seguintes fontes:

```
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
```

O `CSS` vai tentar estilizar com a primeira fonte declarada, se ela existir no computador do leitor, nesse caso a fonte `"Palatino Linotype"` será exibida,e se caso ela não estiver presente, o estilo `CSS` tentará ser feito com a segunda fonte. E por fim, se não tiver nenhuma das fonte no computador do usuário, o browser mostrará uma fonte padrão do sistema. Recomenda - se que a última fonte da lista seja  uma fonte genérica: `serif`, `sans-serif`, `monospace`, `cursive` ou `fantasy`. Isso permiti que o navegador escolha uma fonte semelhante na família genérica, se nenhuma outra fonte estiver disponível.

Existe tambem a biblioteca [Google Web Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), que contem fontes próprias para web e todas testadas e aprovadas pela plataforma google.

**Usando o `@import`:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
```

Ultilizando a fonte na tag desejada:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

**Lembre-se:** O `@import` é um elemento `CSS`, então caso seja colocado no `<head>` do `HTML`, ele sempre devera ficar dentro de uma tag `<style>` .

**Usando a tag `<link>`:**

A tag `<link>`, diferente do `@import` vai direto no `<head>` do `HTML`. Veja o exemplo com a mesma fonte usada no exemplo acima.

```
<head>
    <title>Google Fonts</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

**Lembrando que o [WebFonts](https://fonts.google.com/) já fornece o código pronto para inserção no seu CSS ou HTML.**

Referencias:

- [Combinações de Fontes Seguras de Web CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)
- [Como e qual a melhor forma de usar fontes com CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191805/como-e-qual-a-melhor-forma-de-usar-fontes-com-css/192591#192591)